# Ant mail task - Issue in sending mail with attachments

Tags: email, ant

When I tried using ant mail task, it doesnot seem to work when it comes sending mail with attachments. The problem I am currently facing is, it sends the attachment(s) content in the body of the email, rather than as attachement, even though verbose output displays as, it is sending with attachment.
As initially it complained for missing jars, I added mail.jar & activation.jar.
Here is the snippet which I tried:

```
<mail mailhost="mailHost.com" messagemimetype="text/html" subject="Test report" >
<from address="mymaild-addr@somedomain.com"/>
<replyto address="mymaild-addr@somedomain.com"/>
<to address="mymaild-addr@somedomain.com"/>
<message> Attached is sample report </message>
<attachments>
<fileset dir="${myRequiredDirectory}">
  <include name="Test.txt"/>
  <include name="Calls.txt"/>
</fileset>
</attachments>
</mail>
```

And I get

```
[mail] Failed to initialise MIME mail: org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer
[mail] Failed to initialise UU mail: Class org.apache.tools.ant.util.ClasspathUtils can not access a member of class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.UUMailer with modifiers ""
[mail] Sending email: Test report
[mail] Sent email with 2 attachments
```

Comment: I am not sure, but does change in mimetype help? I mean you can remove  the attribute, so that it can take the default value

Comment: No, it doesn't. By default mimetype will be text/plain. I tried without specifying it also. It din't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked fine, after adding another dependent jar 'ant-javamail.jar'.